# Re-leveling a 12x16 shed on gravel

Tags: shed, leveling, gravel

I've got a 3 yr old 12x16 shed on a gravel pad.   I put down driveway cloth, then 4" #2 stone- tamped and drove a machine over it for a bit-- then added 4" of crusher run and repeated.    My plan was to rent a power tamper for a day -but the shed got here and it seemed 'good enough'.

Now the 4x4 skids have settled into the gravel a 1-3 inches.[I'm 71 & still learning]

So- I'm jacking it up and my initial thought was to slide treated 2x6s across every couple of feet.

The more I think about it I wonder if I might be better off making 24x24x3" PT pads  and running them every 6' around the perimeter.  [and probably making a trap door in the center of the shed for another]

There are 5 4x4 PT runners- and the joists resting on them are 2x6's on 16" centers.

Seems like this method would make future leveling much easier, and I think the 2x2 pads are less likely to work their way down into the gravel than a 2x6 would.

I've got lots of time and a few barn jacks and a couple hydraulics so it is going up slow, but sure.

Does someone have a comment-- or a better idea?

Thanks-  Jim

Comment: maybe use pavers (or other mansonry components) instead of lumber as the foundation.

Comment: What are you going to jack against? If you put those hydraulic jacks directly onto the gravel, they're just about as likely to push into the gravel as they are to lift the shed, especially since the gravel is soft enough to have allowed the shed to settle in the first place.

Comment: Thanks to @Jasen & FreeMan . I hadn't thought about those large pavers.  Good thought. --    As to jacking, the ground outside the pad is firm and a bit of 2x4 has been sufficient for a base.    I've got it jacked up nearly to where I want it.